# networkx edges between subgraphs

Tags: python, networkx

I have a Graph (G) where nodes are split into two distinct subgraphs (H, I). The nodes within each subgraph are interconnected. What I'm looking for is a list of edges that are connections between the subgraphs and only those in a way thats somewhat scaleable to big graphs.

Setup:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.path_graph(10)
H = nx.subgraph(G, [0,1,2,3,4])
I = nx.subgraph(G, [5,6,7,8,9])
G.add_edge(1,7)
G.add_edge(2,9)
```

Output I want:

```
 [(4,5),(1,7),(2,9)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply loop over the edges and check whether they belong to the different graphs.

This should be O(n) are graphs behave like sets:

```
out = [e for e in G.edges
       if e[0] in H and e[1] in I
       or e[0] in I and e[1] in H]
```

output:

```
[(1, 7), (2, 9), (4, 5)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution without python loops

```
A = nx.adjacency_matrix(G)

h = np.zeros(10)
h[list(H.nodes())] = 1

i = np.zeros(10)
i[list(I.nodes())] = 1

_A = i*(h*A.transpose()).transpose()

H_I = nx.from_pandas_adjacency(pd.DataFrame(_A.todense()))

print(list(H_I.edges))
```